# Angular: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

Not sure where this is happening. The page is functional but I would like to get rid of the error. so with that being said I believe this is sourcing from my custom pipe and it's usage. I have a pipe with the following:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sortby'
})

export class SortbyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

and then the component is this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetEmailsService } from '../../services/get-emails.service';
import { GroupPipe } from '../../pipes/group.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-emails',
    templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
    providers: [GroupPipe]
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

    results: any;
    grouped: any;

    constructor(
        private getEmailsService: GetEmailsService,
        private groupPipe: GroupPipe
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.getEmailsService.emailsAPI().subscribe(
            data => {
                const firstChar: any = null;
                this.results = data;
                this.grouped = this.groupPipe.transform(this.results, 'key');
            }
        );

    }
}
```

and my template looks like this:

```
<div class="row mb-5" *ngFor="let groups of grouped | sortby:'key'">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="rolodex">{{groups.key}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3" *ngFor="let email of groups.value">
                ...do some stuff here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have tried to fix this using `*ngFor="let groups of grouped? | sortby:'key'"` and `*ngFor="let groups? of grouped | sortby:'key'"` but it does not work and completely breaks everything. Any suggestions on what is going on here?

Comment: The A in AJAX means **asynchronous**. That's why emailsAPI() returns an Observable, and not the array directly. So, while the HTTP response hasn't come back, the array that you try to sort doesn't exist, and is thus undefined.

Comment: so maybe wrap my sort function in a conditional to test for a response first?

Comment: You shouldn't sort using a pipe in the first place (see why here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). But yes, you need to avoid sorting undefined (using an ngIf, for example), or to make your pipe deal with null/undefined arrays.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet I believe I fixed it. See below. Is this how you would recommend doing this?

Answer (score 0):

based on @JB Nizets comment i did this:

removed `| sortby:'key'` from the template and then modified my component to use pipe at the component level:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetEmailsService } from '../../services/get-emails.service';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { GroupPipe } from '../../pipes/group.pipe';
import { SortbyPipe } from '../../pipes/sortby.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-emails',
    templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
    providers: [
      GroupPipe,
      SortbyPipe
    ]
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

    results: any;
    grouped: any;

    constructor(
        private getEmailsService: GetEmailsService,
        private groupPipe: GroupPipe,
        private sortbyPipe: SortbyPipe
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.getEmailsService.emailsAPI().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results = data;
                this.grouped = this.sortbyPipe.transform(this.groupPipe.transform(this.results, 'key'), 'key');
            }
        );

    }

}
```